# Single Bloc (actually cubit) with multiple repositories

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, bloc

I have the following scenario:

1. multiple firebase collections
2. multiple FirebaseDataRepositories, all with simple CRUD API
3. single cubit loading all the collections (not the question, as i might split per repository)

Question:

Is there a way implement this, so that I dont have to have so much repetition?
I have a "hunch" that a "FirebaseMultiRepository" could be implemented to achieve this, but I just can't figure out how actually implement it. Maybe some sort of abstract class?

Any ideas are appreciated!

This is the current structure of the implementation:
[image]